# Proper interpretation of statistical power for 2 proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation, statistical-power

I have test results from 2 suppliers.

- 20 samples from Supplier 1 resulted in 8 units passing a test and 12 units failing; a failure proportion of 0.6
- 20 samples from Supplier 2 resulted in 2 units passing and 18 units failing; a failure proportion of 0.9

Minitab produces a Power Value of `0.719743` with inputs:

```
Alternative Hypothesis p1 < p2
Significance Level = 0.05
Each Sample Size = 20
p1=0.6
p2=0.9
```

I have two questions:

1. Would you consider the following statement to be the proper interpretation of these results (i.e., true, relevant and clear), or can it be improved?

   *The Null Hypothesis is that the Supplier 1 failure proportion is greater than the Supplier 2 failure proportion and based on the Minitab analysis results there is a 71.97% probability that we are correctly rejecting this Null Hypothesis, therefore accepting the Alternative Hypothesis is prudent. We are 1- alpha or 95% confident in this statement.*

   Is there anything else that can be stated here that provides insight regarding the belief/degree that the population of product from Supplier 1 is likely to be superior to the population of product from Supplier 2?
2. Why there is a slight difference in the computed power if I run the same analysis using the [pss4 on-line calculator](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~statctr/calculators/pss4.html)?

   I get a power value of 70.75% selecting the 1-sided option. In general, is one of these tools more accurate, true or appropriate for engineering calculations and decision making than the other?

Comment: Hello experts, is there any additional information I can add to clarify this question ?

Comment: There is no reason to do power analysis _after_ you've done the experiment. See [this page](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/Power/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > *The Null Hypothesis is that the Supplier 1 failure proportion is greater than the Supplier 2 failure proportion and based on the Minitab analysis results there is a 71.97% probability that we are correctly rejecting this Null Hypothesis, therefore accepting the Alternative Hypothesis is prudent. We are 1- alpha or 95% confident in this statement.*

   That isn't the correct interpretation of a power analysis.  You don't know if you are correct in concluding that p1 > p2, and you never will.  If you want to make a decision while holding your long run type I error rate at alpha, you should conduct a hypothesis test (e.g., a z-test for difference of two independent proportions) using that alpha.

   A power analysis helps you think through what would happen in the future, if you ran a study *where the truth was the two proportions were .6 and .9*.  The answer is that you would have a 72% probability of correctly rejecting the null.
2. I don't know why there is a difference.  The difference isn't very big ~1.25%.  Be aware that there are different versions of the test for differences in proportions (e.g., to employ the continuity correction or not), and that there is a limit to the precision of the answer due to the numerical methods employed to compute it.